# mysql date range query, when the field is not sent anything for the 'between' statement

Tags: mysql

[I have this query, which returns me 7 records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAAgk.png)

[Now if I add this line 'AND date_format (ds.date_emission,'% Y-% m-% d ') BETWEEN' 'AND' '', nothing returns me, I want that when the date range is empty I need that I also returned the 7 records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvnze.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer answer below.
I have added two variable replace `inStartDate` variable with a range start date and `inEndDate` with range end date.

```
SELECT ds.id
FROM documentos_salida ds
WHERE ds.terceros_id = 329
AND ds.estado =0
AND ds.tipo_documento ='Factura'
AND ds.saldo_pendiente_factura >0
AND (ds.fecha_vencimiento > now() or
 ds.fetcha_vencimiento = NOW())
 AND ds.numero_documento LIKE '%%'
 AND ( CASE WHEN (inStartDate = '' AND inEndDate = '') 
        THEN TRUE 
        ELSE (date_format(ds.fetcha_emision, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN inStartDate AND inStartDate)
        END)
 ORDER BY ds.fecha_emision DESC;
```